# Library to generate a CHM file

Tags: c++, chm

I have been looking for a library that will expose functionality to allow me to generate CHM files. As far as I can tell, that does not exist and I will have to rely on CHMBuilder (in SandCastle) but I thought I would ask before going that route.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Microsoft offers a tool as a free download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en and at any rate, Microsoft is abandoning the CHM format in lieu of a new format : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Assistance_Markup_Language . Though the CHM file is just HTML files so you could use 7-Zip to extract them or use Microsoft's tool at the command line to build the CHM file.

Comment: @0A0D: Let Microsoft do what they want to do. People still have to maintain their earlier creations. And the HTML Workshop has horrible interface and it is difficult to script.

Comment: @liori: Fair enough, I don't care about Microsoft either. I have never used it so take my comment as just a suggestion which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: If only because the newer substitutes are not available default on XP. And XP is simply a version that can't be ignored yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Microsoft HTML Help SDK**

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am selecting this as the answer not because it is what you may be looking for but because it helped me make my own. If you are doing any sort of serious work, do NOT use the help SDK directly, it is badly written imo (may improve later, who knows). I would recommend writing your own with the help of this SDK's project files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib, and a (cross-platfomr) commandtool in Free Pascal. It is in Pascal (Delphi dialect) though.